# Left anti join in spark 1.6.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes: `bigDF` and `smallDF`.

From the `bigDF` I only want the columns not in `smallDF`.

The `smallDF` contains only ID that I don't want to have in the `bigDF`

What I have to do now is:

```
bigDF.join(broadcast(smallDF), Seq("id"), "left_anti")
```

The problem is, that spark 1.6.0 does not support a left_anti join.

Is there another way to implement this?

P.S. The bigDF should not be shuffled (that's why I use `broadcast()`)

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

as `smallDF` is small, you can collect the ids and use the negation of `isin` as:

```
bigDF
.where(!$"id".isin(smallDF.select($"id").distinct.map(_.getInt(0)).collect():_*))
```

Comment: Actually no, as the `smallDF` was not small enough, the driver did not respond anymore...
In the end i used a left join, `where smallDF.id is null`